# If Russia is funding right-wing politicians within the EU, why doesn't the EU return the favor and start funding Putin's opponents in Russia?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, financing

There are [numerous reports](https://news.vice.com/story/marine-le-pen-france-far-right-russias) about how Russia is financing right-wing politicians within the EU in order to unbalance the Union. But why doesn't the EU return the favor and start funding people like [Alexei Navalny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Navalny) or [Mikhail Khodorkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Khodorkovsky)?

Russia already claims that "the West" is funding it's opposition, so it wouldn't give any more ammunition to Russian propaganda.

Comment: Removed some comments that were attempting to answer the question, that is _not_ [what comments are for](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If you feel you can answer the question, please consider posting a [proper answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several points in your question which need to be separated.

First, this article you've linked asserts that there is a deliberate campaign from the Russian government which tries to influence the French elections. For this, various subjects are identified:

- Putin
- the Russian Government
- Russian banks
- a former KGB agent
- members of the Russian parliament
- an ally of Putin
- a Russian NGO
- Kremlin officials
- Russian authorities
- three French NGOs
- Russian state media outlets RT and Sputnik
- a "structured group" of hackers "based in Russia"

Let us assume that this is all true and uncontroversial (which it is not), and that the actions of all these subjects are not independent but orchestrated from the top, for which this article provides no proof whatsoever.
Then we can already see that structure of the alleged influence: there is just little direct influence by the Russian government or Putin, but mostly over indirect channels such as other members of the Russian Parliament, NGOs, and state-financed media outlets. So these are the channels that we should also look into the other way round.

Secondly, you assume the EU does nothing to support Russian dissidents, which is untrue.

Official support directly from the EU is quite difficult. The EU has a [complicated constitutional structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union#Governance) to reach political decisions, and a large bureaucracy. So official support by highest EU institutions, if it were intended, would also face various obstacles. There is an [official program](https://eeas.europa.eu/headquarters/headquarters-homepage/720/russian-federation-and-european-union-eu_en#Human+rights+dialogue)  to support human rights, however it seems the usual [EU](https://ec.europa.eu/europeaid/how/finance/eidhr_en.htm_en) bureaucratic nightmare to apply for such a grant, see e.g. the following [old example](http://www.con-eu.de/eu-ausschreibung-451.html).

There are examples of direct funding of Russian NGOs by the EU, see http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/02/world/europe/russia-puts-pressure-on-elections-monitor-golos.html

Some of the authorities of the EU could, however, take personally a supporting role for dissidents. They are:

1. The head of the European Council, Donald Tusk
2. The head of the European Commission, Jean-Claude Juncker
3. The president of the EU parliament, until recently Martin Schulz
4. The EU high representative, Federica Mogherini.

I will here deal only with the last two.

Federica Mogherini has been [criticized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federica_Mogherini#Relations_with_Russia) by a large group of the European security elite for taking a 'weak' stance against Russia, see [here](http://www.politico.eu/article/vladimir-putin-opponents-pile-onto-federica-mogherini-eaststratcom-sandra-kalniete-jakub-janda-estonia-atlantic-council-ben-nimmo-fake-news-russia-putin-europe-foreign-policy/) or [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federica_Mogherini#cite_note-EVletter-18). Actually, on the list of signatories, there is Garry Kasparov, another Russian dissident. So you see here already some involvement between think tanks and a Russian dissident.

For Martin Schulz, a quick glance on the [Khodorkovsky website](https://www.khodorkovsky.com/) (as of April 25 2017) shows that there are EU activities, for instance the [Boris Nemtsov Forum in Brussels](https://www.khodorkovsky.com/resources/boris-nemtsov-forum-brussels/), where Martin Schulz, the then-presiding President of the European Parliament, was attending (see [other speakers](https://nemtsovforum.org/speakers/) including other members of the EU parliament) The Nemzow Forum lists as its partners the major fractions of the [EU parliament](https://nemtsovforum.org/brussels-november-16-17/) as well as the [Friedrich-Naumann Foundation for Freedom](http://fnst.org/) which is related to the German Liberal Party.

The main influence into the internal business of foreign states actually happens via such think tanks and party political foundations. Especially German party political foundations have a long history of influencing the inner politics of foreign states, and particularly in supporting the opposition in states which oppose the foreign policy goals of the German government. I've provided already the connection of the Friedrich Naumann Foundation, similar connections can be found for other political party foundations in germany. That's why the Russian authorities also targeted them in a [crackdown](http://www.spiegel.de/international/europe/russian-authorities-raid-german-foundations-and-ngos-a-890969.html) to prevent further meddling into the internal politics of Russia.

So as some commenters metioned before, the western powers first started by interfering into Russian politics, not least by their unequivocal support for Yeltzin, who even commanded tanks to shoot at the Parliament (can one be more anti-democratic than that? Yet, Putin is the bad guy and Yeltzin was an angel in the western press. But this is another story…)

Comment: Yeah, the State Duma of October 1993 had been elected in 1990 with only the communist party running and a handful of indepedents. The communists had like 80%+ of the seats, at least at election time (920 of 1,068). I means sure blowing up the *armed* putchists holed up in the parliament building was horribly "undemocratic". Let's just call it what it was: a [mini] civil war.

Comment: RFERL has some photos, BTW of "parliamentary" opposition of that day https://gdb.rferl.org/342A6DE0-9931-48CC-AEC2-702D75AD4A37_w1023_s.jpg

Comment: Imagine dozens of people with Kalashnikovs [or make that M-16s] took over the Capitol building. What do you think the US army [be it the National Guard] would do? Just fire tear gas at them?

Comment: Here's the [now imprisoned] Kara-Murza writing about it: "The real issue is that, unlike what its present-day apologists suggest, the Congress was not a symbol of parliamentarianism and democracy, but the last vestige of the illegitimate Soviet system established after the October 1917 coup d’état. It is not often mentioned that RSFSR people’s deputies’ elections in March 1990 were still held under Article 6 of the Soviet Constitution, which enshrined the one-party system and established the Communist Party as “the leading and guiding force of the Soviet society.""

Comment: "Eighty-six percent of the people’s deputies elected in 1990 were members of the Communist Party. Vitaly Vorotnikov, chairman of the presidium of the RSFSR Supreme Soviet, noted with some satisfaction that never before had the Communists achieved such superiority over nonpartisans in the republic’s legislature."

Comment: ""In December 1992, the Kremlin and the Supreme Soviet reached a deal brokered by Constitutional Court Chairman Valery Zorkin [...] Yeltsin delivered his side of the bargain—Gaidar was replaced by Viktor Chernomyrdin, a protégé of the “red directors.” But the Congress, after initially agreeing to hold a constitutional referendum on April 11, 1993, went back on its word."

Comment: "The deputies were happy with the status quo—the continued existence of Brezhnev’s 1978 Constitution that could be amended anytime the majority of the Congress wished. In 1992 and 1993, Kremlin librarians joked that they never had the up-to-date version of the Russian Constitution, since it was amended by the Congress so frequently. The joke was not funny. That situation had nothing to do with democracy or the rule of law."

Comment: "Yeltsin continued to seek compromise with his opponents. The government did not use force after the “White House defenders” spilled the first blood on September 23 [...] Nor did it use force after Supreme Soviet leaders began handing out weapons (including automatic weapons) en masse to their supporters. [...] The confrontation entered its second week. No storming of the White House was attempted. On the contrary, on October 1, talks between the opposing camps began at the St. Daniel Monastery under the auspices of Patriarch Alexy II."

Comment: "In the early hours of October 2, the representatives of both sides (Sergei Filatov, Yuri Luzhkov, and Oleg Soskovets on behalf of the president; Veniamin Sokolov and Ramazan Abdulatipov on behalf of the Supreme Soviet) concluded “Protocol #1,” which provided for the gradual lifting of the blockade and the restoration of electricity to the White House, as well as the accounting and storing of unauthorized weapons that were being held in the building."

Comment: "But the deputies annulled the protocol on the same day, declaring that the requirement to account for the weapons was illegal and accusing Sokolov and Abdulatipov of “exceeding their authority.”"

Comment: "Shortly before 4 p.m. on October 3—around the time the talks at the monastery were supposed to restart—Vice President Alexander Rutskoi and Supreme Soviet Speaker Ruslan Khasbulatov addressed their supporters from the White House balcony. “Young people, battle-ready men! Form ranks here, in the left section; today we must storm and take over the [Moscow] City Hall and Ostankino [television center],” commanded the vice president. “I call on our valiant warriors to bring troops and tanks here in order to storm the Kremlin with the usurper, former criminal Yeltsin!” declared the speaker."

Comment: Imagine the equivalent situation in the US: if the VP gathered armed men around the Capitol and asked them to storm the White House. How do you think that could end?

Comment: N.B. It's technically true that the Supreme Soviet had legally impeached Yeltsin at that point. But this was a Soviet elected under a one-party system and which didn't seem in any hurry to change the constitution to something more, uhh. actually democratic. Yeltsin had just survived a confidence referendum (called by the Soviet in April '93) on his tenure and economic policies. (The Soviet called that instead of a constitutional referendum)) So there's that democratic angle.

Comment: Results of that referendum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Russian_government_referendum#Results (called entirely by the Soviet, Yeltsin had no say in the wording of the question. The early elections for parliament were rejected because of the unreasonably high quorum set for that. They didn't use the same quorum for the presidential one. In fact, they tried to make it so that he would have needed 50% of the registered electorate to keep his job, but the Supreme Court modified that to 50% of those who actually voted.)

Comment: Rather aside, but with Rutskoy in charge, we would probably have seen the post-2014 war back in '94. Among other things he was calling for Crimea to be given to Russia. (In case you wonder why the West was not enthusiastic about him.) And yeah, he called for that in April 1992, not sometime later, albeit it was disguised merely as a call for Crimea's independence from Ukraine then. https://www.refworld.org/docid/469f38ec2.html

Comment: And one of the funny things in that piece "Jul 21, 1993: The UNSC declares the Russian parliament's resolution on Sevastopol in violation of the UN Charter and the 1990 Russo-Ukrainian treaty establishing their common borders." Of course, that was only possible because Russia's representative at the UNSC obeyed Yeltsin (and not the Soviet).

Comment: And in case you wondered, the Soviet had tried to essentially annex Sevastopol by declaring it a federal Russian city https://www.un.org/en/sc/repertoire/93-95/Chapter%208/EUROPE/93-95_8-22-UKRAINE.pdf

Comment: As for Rutskoy's [popularity](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/peoples-party-free-russia): 
"Rutskoi called upon the delegates to participate in the creation of the social-patriotic movement Power [...] In 1996, Power was unable to collect the required number of signatures for its presidential candidate Rutskoi, and it joined with the bloc of popular-patriotic forces headed by Gennady Zyuganov. Soon afterward, Rutskoi was elected first as cochair of the Popular-Patriotic Union of Russia, and then, with its support, governor of Kursk Oblast."